# Nativescript Angular ActivityIndicator spinner - how do I change its size in ios?

Tags: ios, nativescript, activity-indicator

As I understand it, the ios version size can be set to either of 2 sizes.  To set the larger size, the following should work.

@ViewChild("spinnerId") spinnerRef: ElementRef;

ngAfterViewInit() {
   if(isIOS) {
      workspinnerRef.nativeElement.ios.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.WhiteLarge;

}
}

My question is how does one import UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle ?? I cannot find it in any of the tns libraries.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I modified my code as per Manoj's suggestion.

I was stumped on this today but found a solution thanks to someone in the Nativescript slack. If you're using NS version 5+, you can implement the following:

.html:

```
<!-- somewhere in your HTML -->
<ActivityIndicator id="activityIndicator" (loaded)="setIOSActivityIndicator()"></ActivityIndicator>
```

.ts:

```
// before your component class
import { ActivityIndicator } from "ui/activity-indicator";
import { Color } from "color"; // for setting a color

declare var UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle: any;    

// inside your component class

setIOSActivityIndicator() {
    let indicator = this.page.getViewById("activityIndicator"); 
    indicator.ios.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge;

    // setting a color
    const color = new Color("your-color-hex-code");
    indicator.ios.color = colorios;
}
```

However, if you're using a version before NS 5, you can implement something like this:

```
// before your component class
declare var UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle: any;    

// inside your component class
ngAfterViewInit() {
    if (isIOS) {
        var indicator = this.page.getViewById("activityIndicator");
        indicator.ios.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge;
    }  
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  I was declaring UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle inside the component and thinking it had to be imported.  Also, the indicator isn't ready at the afterViewInit hook as your example shows.

Comment: The indicator changes size & color after several seconds.  I set a .1 second timeout, but the delay to when the size & color is actually set is much longer.

Comment: Which version of NS are you using? The second solution was working for me when I was using 4.0, but upgrading to 5.0 broke the activity indicator until I managed to arrive at the first solution.

Comment: Try using the `loaded` event of activity indicator itself by then the native instance will be accessible.

Comment: Thanks for that tip Manoj, I've edited my original post.

Answer (score -1):

Simple !

```
<ActivityIndicator color="green" busy="true" height="50" width="50"></ActivityIndicator>
```

here is the [NativeScript Playground link](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=LIjEH6)

Comment: That seems to change the amount of space allocated to the spinner, but not the size of the spinner.